# HTaccess conflict with each other on php rewrite and file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this original .htaccess at my folder

**/subfolder/offer/dl**

```
AddType application/octet-stream .txt
```

The purpose was to force direct download on txt file on click on any .txt extension e.g

```
http://example.com/subfolder/offer/dl/1.txt
```

The above url will download the txt file instead of show it at browser.

Then recently at the folder offer, I added the following .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/offer/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&action_id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Now due to this .htaccess, my above .htaccess for /dl folder doesn't work, it won't download or link to the file

What should I change to make both works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a rule to ignore all requests inside `/dl/` folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/offer/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /dl/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&action_id=$2 [L,QSA]
```